# posting/get multiple data to server in flutter using php and mysql

Tags: php, flutter

I have tried different ways but non to be working! i believe there's something i am not doing right! can any one show me how to simply post different files, mostly images to a local xamp server in flutter with php to mysql with any package but mostly http, am running my app using an emulator..

Answer (score 1):

You can access the localhost of you PC using 10.0.2.2
it proxied to 127.0.0.1

For POST/GETs I recommend you use Dio (https://pub.dev/packages/dio) plugin for flutter.
Read the DIO Docs it has examples of sending files.
Quoting from Dio Documentation,

GET

```
Response response = await Dio().get("http://www.google.com");
```

POST

```
response = await dio.post(
  "http://www.dtworkroom.com/doris/1/2.0.0/test",
  data: {"aa": "bb" * 22},
  onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
    print("$sent $total");
  },
);
```